Is this historical fiction question on topic?
YA or children's book about the Trojan war, focusing heavily on Helen, where a "magic" stone of Troy was important
I've read The Luck of Troy; there are precisely zero fantasy elements in it. The statuette the asker mentions is believed by the Trojans to protect their city, but that is all it is: a religious belief. The gods make no appearance, unlike in the Iliad, the source material.
The book is firmly historical fiction. Is it considered on topic because The Iliad is? Or is it one of those blurry lines situations?
Just curious.

^ I proposed this one as the dupe-target since the OP of that story did believe it was a fantasy question ("the thing that sticks in my mind is this magical stone")

There are no such things as "fantasy elements". The absence of so-called "fantasy elements" does not mean that a work is not fantasy, and their presence in a mainstream work (e.g. the ghost in Hamlet) does not make it fantasy. Fantasy is a marketing category. If it's marketed as fantasy, it's fantasy; otherwise not.

And while that's true, we have to have some standard for what is, or isn't on-topic on a site aimed at science fiction or fantasy. Or else why bother? We could just merge with Movies:SE and Literature:SE and Mythology:SE. We've always allowed a generous scope for stories which contain SF'nal elements, even if the main body is mundane.

The actual "luck of Troy" mentioned in the title is a statuette of Pallas Athena:

little black stone image of Pallas Athena which fell from heaven right
on the spot where it stands in the kella of the Temple ... The very
Temple was built round it. And the city in which it stands can never
be conquered.’

This seems quite clearly to be a "fantastic element": a magic stone with magical properties. Whether its origin and its powers were true or not, most of the characters in the book believe it to be true. And nothing in the narrative disproves their belief - the city remains unconquered until the image is stolen by Odysseus. As Jenayah remarked in comments, the magical stone was the plot element recalled by the OP. The fact that the answer turned out to be so-called "historical fiction"1 does not invalidate that the question as asked was a fantasy question.
 1. Terming the Iliad "historical fiction" also seems rather ridiculous to me. Is the Odyssey also historical fiction? 

The stone is an icon believed to impart luck. That's not quite the same as it having supernatural powers, any more than a story about me losing my lucky socks before going to a job interview is a work of fantasy.

Suppose I had a lucky gold ring which I thought could only be destroyed by throwing it into a volcano. Would a story about that be a work of fantasy?

If I wrote a story about losing my lucky coin and not wanting to go to the casino, and instead going to get a burger, would that story be on-topic?

Just to clarify, I wasn't referring to The Iliad as historical fiction. It has magic and gods in it, so clearly fantasy. That makes it on topic, so I was asking if that made The Luck of Troy on topic.

@Moriarty - The Iliad is a work of mythology. That would (typically) make it off-topic for our site. It used to be someone's actual religion.

I've voted to close it. Works of historical fiction are off-topic, as are works based on real-world mythology, particularly those that don't contain any science fiction or fantasy content.
We've had a few meta questions about this subject and the small consensus was that these sorts of works are off-topic. Since that's the case, a story-id question that led to one of these would also be off-topic.

Can I ask about mythology?

Should myths be considered religions?


